# How to cast type of one column's values from another column which contains 'type'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

**What my df looks like -**

```
data = [("A", "2.1", "float"), ("B", "-2.0", "float"), ("C", "5.45", "int"), ("D", "John", "str"), ("E", "['US', 'UE']", "list"), ("F", "{'alive': True}", "dict")]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['vname','value','type'])
print(df)

    vname            value  type
0     A              2.1    float
1     B               -2    float
2     C              5.45   int
3     D             John    str
4     E         [US, UE]    list
5     F  {'alive': True}    dict

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   vname   6 non-null      object
 1   value   6 non-null      object
 2   type    6 non-null      object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 272.0+ bytes
```

**What i want is dictionary like -**

```
{ 'A':2.1, 'B':-2.0, 'C':5, 'D':'John', 'E':['US','UE'], 'F':{'alive': True} }
```

**Note - The problem is that, I have values from the `value` column with type `str`**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` function.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [
...     ("A", 2.1, "float"),
...     ("B", -2.0, "float"),
...     ("C", 500, "int"),
...     ("D", "John", "str"),
...     ("E", ["US", "UE"], "list"),
...     ("F", {"alive": True}, "dict"),
... ]
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["vname", "value", "type"])
>>> my_dict = dict(zip(df["vname"], df["value"]))
>>> print(type(my_dict["A"]))
<class 'float'>
>>> print(type(my_dict["B"]))
<class 'float'>
>>> print(type(my_dict["D"]))
<class 'str'>
>>> print(type(my_dict["E"]))
<class 'list'>
>>> print(type(my_dict["F"]))
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Problem with this answer is the OP has strings for the float and int values not as in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

### `Solution`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [('A', 2.1, 'float'), ('B', -2.0, 'float'), ('C', 500, 'int'), ('D', 'John', 'str'), ('E', ['US', 'UE'], 'list'), ('F', {'alive': True}, 'dict')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['vname','value','type'])
```

```py
print(df)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
  vname  ...   type
0     A  ...  float
1     B  ...  float
2     C  ...    int
3     D  ...    str
4     E  ...   list
5     F  ...   dict

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

```py
print(df.info())
```

`OUTPUT`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
vname    6 non-null object
value    6 non-null object
type     6 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 272.0+ bytes
None
```

```py
print(dict(zip(df['vname'], df['value'])))
```

`OUTPUT`

```
{'A': 2.1, 'B': -2.0, 'C': 500, 'D': 'John', 'E': ['US', 'UE'], 'F': {'alive': True}}
```

Comment: This is the same solution as already provided by @Abdul

Comment: Problem with this answer is the OP has strings for the float and int etc values not as in your sample data.

Answer (score -1):

A simple conversion  [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) should preserve the original types if you really have the DataFrame as provided:

```
df.set_index('vname')['value'].to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'A': 2.1, 'B': -2.0, 'C': 500, 'D': 'John', 'E': ['US', 'UE'], 'F': {'alive': True}}
```

If really you have strings in "value" (`df['value'] = df['value'].astype(str)`) you can convert using:

```
from ast import literal_eval

values = (df.groupby('type', group_keys=False)['value']
            .apply(lambda g: g.apply(literal_eval)
                             if g.name in ['list', 'dict']
                             else g.astype(g.name))
         )

out = dict(zip(df['vname'], values))
```